# Deleting lines from large file if strings in list are found in the first 12 characters of line?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file matrix of +184000 lines * +5400 rows that looks like this

```
denovo1 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400.........
denovo10 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400........
denovo100 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400.......
denovo1000 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400......
denovo10000 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400.....
denovo100000 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400......
denovo184117 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400......
```

I have a list of identifiers in second file file that looks like this:

```
denovo1
denovo100
denovo1000
denovo100000
```

I wish to purge the lines in matrix 1 if the identifier is found in file 2. Thus:

```
denovo10 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400........
denovo10000 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400.....
denovo184117 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400......
```

I have this short unix code that reads line by line and finds the strings in file 2:

```
while read -r line
do
echo $line
sed -i '' '/$line/d' /my/path/matrix1
done < /my/path/file2
```

and it does work, but it takes forever because it reads all the lines to the end. Is there some way to make the machine read only the first 12 characters of each line?

Answer (score 1):

With `grep`:

```
grep -vwf file matrix > matrix.new
mv matrix.new matrix
```

- option `-f FILE` use `FILE` as pattern input file
- option `-w` select only those lines containing matches that form whole words
- option `-v` select non-matching lines

Note that `file` must not contain any empty lines.

Or if you create your identifier file manually with an anchor `^` to match the start of the line and a space character after each identifier to mark the end of the pattern:

```
printf '^%s \n' denovo{1,100,1000,100000} > file
grep -vf file matrix > matrix.new
mv matrix.new matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{ids[$1]; next} !($1 in ids)' ids file
denovo10 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400........
denovo10000 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400.....
denovo184117 someverylaaargenumbers and lotandlotsoftextuntil 5400......
```

How it works:

- `FNR==NR{ids[$1]; next}`

  While reading the first file, `ids`, this creates a key in associative array `ids` with the id.  It then skips the rest of the commands and jumps to the `next` line.
- `!($1 in ids)`

  While reading the second file, this prints the line if the first field is not a key in associative array `ids`.

#### To update the original file

When you are satisfied that the code is working correctly, the file can be changed:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ids[$1]; next} !($1 in ids)' ids file >tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: Sorry for being a moron in awk. I don't understand where to put the file names in your example. If the first file's name is matrix 1, and file2 contains the identifiers, then how should the command look?

Comment: awk 'FNR==NR{ids[matrix1]; next} !($1 in ids)' ids file2?

Comment: If `file2` is the identifiers and the data is in `matrix 1`, then use: `awk 'FNR==NR{ids[$1]; next} !($1 in ids)'  file2 "matrix 1"`.

Comment: `FNR==NR` Yuck!!! (btw, "Yuck!" is probably the proper way to pronounce `awk`.) LOL

Comment: You are free to look at `awk` that way if you want, @filbranden, but you'll be missing out on one of Unix's most useful scripting/glue tools.

Comment: @John1024 awk is totally fine for very simple things, selecting a single column or doing a running sum... But as with many Unix tools (and I do put bourne shell in this same box!) it just doesn't scale and you need to resort to tricks like this. At some point, using a real programming language is the proper solution. When you need something that can be tested (i.e. unit tests) and maintainable.